# C# Grouping numbers another way

Tags: c#, linq

When grouping numbers ,I use

```
   string[] numbers = 
   { "123", "34555", "91882", "100", "7823", "1111", "76551" };

    var query = from digits in numbers
                group digits by digits.Length into ByDigit
                select
                new { digit = ByDigit, length = ByDigit.Key };
```

When i suppose to use

`var query = numbers.GroupBy() (` I do't know how to name it ,is it extension chaining ?)

what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to know how to use the extension methods to do the same thing. In this case it would be

```
var query = numbers.GroupBy(n => n.Length).Select(n => new { digit = n, length = n.Key });
```

Comment: oh! Yes I mean extension method

Answer (score 4):

Using same semantics, you'll have:

```
var query = numbers
    .GroupBy(digits => digits.Length)
    .Select(ByDigit => new
    {
        digit = ByDigit,
        length = ByDigit.Key
    });
```